# No Partition to install Yosemite to

Tags: install, startup, partition, macos

I wanted to have a clean Yosemite installation.
Therefor I deleted the existing partition to make sure a completely clean installation is made.
The problem is that I cannot choose the partition to install to any more.
After accepting the license there is no partition to select from. Except for the recovery partition itself.
Macintosh HD is still there in the partition tool. but I cannot select it or rework it in any way because all options are greyed out.

Tried booting via recovery partition and stick.

How do I get back to having a partition to install to?

[image: screenshot from partition tool]
[image]

Comment: Dieses Volume is geschützt = it is locked/protected, and you can not use the Recovery Partition anyway for that.

Comment: Can you post the results of running "diskutil list" in the terminal? And also "diskutil cs list"

Comment: I had a similar problem when install Yosemite, due to the disk being converted to a Logical Volume Group, or "Logische Volumegruppe" as you'll see there.

Comment: One more thing: will Disk Utility let you verify/repair the disk in the "first aid" tab?

Comment: @ChrisA I can check the drive and received no indication something is wrong. It does not attempt to repair anything. How can I post it? It is a long list to type off... Any alternative to get it?

Comment: @Buscar웃 you are right, but why is the other partition not shown? Well, I cancelled a previous installation where the drive was being encrypted. But I did it the soft way. Not by switching the MacBook off. So I see no reason the drive is not there.

Comment: I am trying to install to a stick now.... Will take a long time. Last night it failed. Something is wrong with the install stick I created. But I tried installing from recovery with same result anyway

Answer (score 1):

This post is for a different problem, but contains the same solution:

[How do I fix my SSD after installing Yosemite and Enabling TRIM? No boot & can't erase](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151252/how-do-i-fix-my-ssd-after-installing-yosemite-and-enabling-trim-no-boot-cant?rq=1)

I had to go to the terminal (it is available in the installation tool) and do as described in the link:

Use `diskutil list`
and check which volume/partition you want to delete (for me the clue was the size corresponding to my hard drive).

Then type `diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ name disk0`.
"name " will be the name of the volume you create.

Close the terminal, go back to the installation tool and install as you would expect.